# How to set the right user for github push

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository with a username - let's call it `githubuser`

I have a workstation again with a username - let's call it `workstationuser`

I cloned the repo on my machine and changed something. Now I want to push the changes to github, so that `githubuser` is the author.

But when I execute `git push origin master` I always get

```
remote: Permission to githubuser/your-repo.git denied to emersoncod.
```

I have no idea how and when this user `emersoncod` was set, I simply cannot get rid of that.

Where could this be configured ? How can I configure it that `githubuser` is pushing ?

Thanks for any help

### Update

I checked the `.git/config` file inside my local checkout

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/githubuser/your-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    name = githubuser
    email = githubuser@example.com
```

### Update 2

And the `.gitconfig` file in my home directory

```
[user]
    name = githubuser
    email = githubuser@example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be one of several reasons:

#### The user is not contributor to the github project

1. Navigate to the repository on Github you wish to share with your collaborator.
2. Click on the `Settings` link in the right side menu, below `Network`
3. On the new page, click the `Collaborators` menu item on the left side of the page.
4. Start typing the new collaborator's GitHub username into the text box.
5. Select the GitHub user from the list that appears below the text box.
6. Click the `Add` button.

Read this out: http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2

---

#### Working with `ssh`

You have to define new keys for the user

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer - but I don't want to add a Collaborator to my GitHub account. I want to commit as the githubuser. my git has somehow a user configured that I don't know how and where to change this. Also I tried the ssh key with the github users email, but it remains the same (but i also cloned the repo with https)

Comment: Use the CLI to set the user & email or edit the .gitconfig file under your home directory. This is for setting the right values for the commit log. In order to be able to push you should use the ssh keys that you generated.

Comment: I updated my post with the content of the `.git/config` file. There is the `githubuser` configured - I find no source where `emersoncod` can come from

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it out myself.

I changed the `git/config` file to

```
url = git@github.com:githubuser/your-repo.git
```

so from `https` to `ssh` and with that it works.

Answer (score 0):

From your repository within GitHub, navigate to the settings screen from the list menu on the right side of the browser. From the settings go to the collaborators section using the link on the left side of the screen. Add your local username (workstationuser) to the list of collaborators and you will be able to push to the repo.

You can use the method mentioned by @Tgsmith61591 to set your username in local repository.